# Render Nunjucks in Jest test

Tags: jestjs, nunjucks

I am trying to create a Jest test for a new page created in Nunjucks and getting errors whichever method I try.

```
    Template render error: (unknown path)
      Template render error: (unknown path)
      Error: template not found: _layout.njk

       8 |     const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../app/views/home.njk')
       9 |     const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8')
    > 10 |     const rendered = nunjucks.renderString(template, { delinkedValuePage: { exists: true } })
```

The variable `templatePath` is the correct relative path from where the test is situated, if I try a different approach and try:

```
const homeContent = require('../../app/views/home.njk')
```

then change templatePath to

```
const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, homeContent)
```

I get a different output which leads me to think that I have been asked to produce a test in a way that Jest isn't intended to be used for:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){{% extends '_layout.njk' %}
                                                                                              ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'
```

Comment: You should use `{% extends` instead of `{{%`.